# Add integers in a dynamic picklist

Tags: visualforce

I want to add number to my dynamic picklist but I am getting an error

> Constructor not defined: [System.SelectOption].(Integer,
>   Integer)

.I am new to this type of coding . I have written a code .Please assist me with this

error I am getting:`Constructor not defined: [System.SelectOption].<Constructor>(Integer, Integer)`

my code:

```
public with sharing class example1Controller {

 Public String SelectedMonth{get;set;}
    //public list<Selectoption> City{get;set;} 

    public List<SelectOption> getMonth() {
        List<SelectOption> MonthOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        MonthOptions.add(new SelectOption('--None--','Month'));
        for(Integer i=01;i<13;i++){
            MonthOptions.add(new SelectOption(i,i));
        }
        return MonthOptions;
    }

}`



<apex:page controller="example1Controller" >
<apex:form>
    <label>
        <span>Month</span>
        <apex:selectList styleClass="small" value="{!SelectedMonth}" multiselect="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!Month}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </label>
</apex:form>
```

here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

More info here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_SelectOption_ctor_2.htm

```
MonthOptions.add(new SelectOption(String.valueOf(i),String.valueOf(i)));
```